# Javascript Sort Duplicates First, then Small to Large Values

Tags: javascript, sorting

Essentially I'd like for duplicate values to rise to the top, then for the remaining values to be ordered from small to large (ascending).

Example of what I need:

```
246, 246, 246, 100, 216, 553, 600
```

This is what my code outputs:

```
100, 216, 246, 246, 246, 553, 600
```

Here's my code:

[Javascript Demo on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/lubekicuri/edit?js,output)

```
// Array of objects
var unsorted = [
    {
        id: 1,
        height: 600
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        height: 246
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        height: 216
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        height: 100
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        height: 553
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        height: 246
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        height: 246
    }
];


// Sort by duplicates, then ascending
var sorted = unsorted.sort(function(a, b) {

  // Attempting to sort duplicates first...
    if (a.height === b.height) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (a.height < b.height) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (a.height > b.height) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}); 

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution you could use written without es6 style, by grouping duplicates into one array and distinct values into another array, sorting each of those individually and then concatenating both:

```js
function duplicateSort(objects) {

  // ordering from smallest to largest
  var ascending = function(prev, next) {
    return prev.height - next.height;
  };

  // sorts an arr with an ascending ordering
  var ascendingSort = function(arr) {
    return arr.sort(ascending);
  };

  // checks if item is a duplicate
  var isDuplicate = function(item) {
    return objects.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.height == item.height
    }).length == 1 ? false : true;
  }

  // checks if item is not a duplicate
  var notDuplicate = function(item) {
    return !isDuplicate(item);
  }

  // partition duplicates vs distinct
  var duplicates = objects.filter(isDuplicate);
  var nonDuplicates = objects.filter(notDuplicate);

  // sort both and flatten/concat into one array
  return [].concat.apply([], [duplicates, nonDuplicates].map(ascendingSort));
}



 var unsorted = [{
    id: 1,
    height: 600
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    height: 246
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    height: 216
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    height: 100
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    height: 553
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    height: 246
  }
];

console.log(duplicateSort(unsorted));
```

A solution using `sort` would be writing a comparator to handle a `duplicate` item by moving it towards the front of the `array` and sorting distinct values normally (*ascending*). Since `sort` only checks 2 numbers at a time, apply this sort to the length of the array amount of times.

```js
function duplicateSort2(arr) {

  // checks if element is a duplicate in this array
  var isDuplicate = function(item) {
    return arr.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.height == item.height
    }).length == 1 ? false : true;
  }

  // custom sort for duplicates
  var ascending = function(prev, next) {
    if (isDuplicate(prev)) return 0;
    if (isDuplicate(next)) return 1;
    return prev.height - next.height;
  }

  // sort on each element
  arr.map(function(item) {
    return arr.sort(ascending);
  });

  return arr;
}

var unsorted = [{id: 1,height: 600},{id: 2,height: 246},{id: 3,height: 216},{id: 4,height: 100},{id: 5,height: 553},{id: 6,height: 246}];

console.log(duplicateSort2(unsorted));
```

Comment: For consistency sake I'd like to not mix ES6 code in with my current code... but I do appreciate the answer... I'm wondering if there is a simpler solution to this?

Comment: I refactored this for you to match your syntax preference.

Answer (score 1):

Change your sort function to this -

```
var sorted = unsorted.sort(function(a, b) {

    // Attempting to sort duplicates first...
    if (a.height === b.height) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (a.height < b.height) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (a.height > b.height) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Hmm... just tried implementing this and it seems ignore duplicates and only sort ascending. http://jsbin.com/vafitafoja/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1):

A callback function for `sort` using ES6,

```
const sortFunc = (a, b) => {
  const diff = a.height - b.height;
  switch (diff) {
    case 0:
        return -1;
    default:
        return diff;
  }
}

unsortedArr.sort(sortFunc);
```

Comment: You should use it. If you do not want you can manually transpile the code to ES5 using babel online

Comment: For sure, but it's not what I'm using now—eventually I will. Also I just ran this function in JS bin and it doesn't appear to output duplicates first... http://jsbin.com/wocekubote/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code will give you the result you wanted.
Strategy: Making two arrays: unique member array, duplicate member array. sort them and then concat them together.

```js
// Array of objects
var unsorted = [
    {
        id: 1,
        height: 600
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        height: 246
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        height: 216
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        height: 100
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        height: 553
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        height: 246
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        height: 246
    }
];


var uniqueHeights = [];
var dupHeights = [];
var findIndexByHeight = function(arr, ele) {
  var index = -1;
  arr.forEach(function(innerEle, innerI) {
    if (ele.height === innerEle.height) {
        index = innerI;
    }
  });
  return index;
}

unsorted.forEach(function(ele, i) {
  if(findIndexByHeight(uniqueHeights, ele) === -1) {
    uniqueHeights.push(ele);
  } else  {
    dupHeights.push(ele);
  }
});

for(var idx = 0; idx < uniqueHeights.length; idx++) {
  var dupIdx = findIndexByHeight(dupHeights, uniqueHeights[idx]);
  if(dupIdx !== -1) {
    dupHeights.push(uniqueHeights.splice(dupIdx, 1)[0]);
    idx--;
  }
}
var sortedDup = dupHeights.sort(function(a, b){
  return a.id > b.id;
});
sortedDup = dupHeights.sort(function(a, b){
  return a.height > b.height;
});
var sortedUnique = uniqueHeights.sort(function(a, b){
  return a.height > b.height;
});
var resArr = sortedDup.concat(sortedUnique);

console.log(resArr);
```